# ¿Cómo organizáis vuestro git local si tenéis más de un ordenador?

Tags: git, github

Tengo un portátil y un sobremesa. En ambos ordenadores existen varios mismos repositorios remotos.

Lo que sucede es que si estoy trabajando en un commit desde el portátil pero no lo finalizo, y después quiero continuar desde mi sobremesa, lo que suelo hacer es crear una rama remota para mis tareas.

Lo que sucede es que esto en un repositorio más colaborativo (con más gente) no lo veo adecuado.

¿Cómo manejar esta situación? ¿Google drive o similar para el repositorio en local?

Comment: Creo que cualquier respuesta se va a basar en opiniones. Aquí va mi opinión: No veo por qué es malo crear ramas, en algunos proyectos es normal incluso crear una rama para cada tarea asignada. Luego, antes de hacer un pull request se hace un rebase, con lo que los cambios se reúnen en un sólo commit, manteniendo limpio el historial de la rama principal

Comment: Gracias @PabloLozano he estado mirando lo que comentas, te refieres a esto cierto? Lo único que sin PR

http://blog.veladan.org/2017/04/19/sourcetree-rebase-interactive/